# Customized streambuffer for C++ istream

Tags: c++, iostream

Basically I implement a traditional file-descriptor-based streambuffer for `istream` operations. The implementation overrides the `sync` and `underflow` functions, while in `sync` the buffer will be automatically enlarged if necessary (just like `vector`).

```
class InputStreamBuffer : public std::basic_streambuf<char> {

  private:

    // small stack buffer optimization
    constexpr static size_t _STACK_BUFSZ = 128;

    static_assert(_STACK_BUFSZ >= 1, "Stack buffer size should be at least 1");

    char_type  _stk [_STACK_BUFSZ];
    char_type* _buf {_stk};

    size_t _size {_STACK_BUFSZ};

    const int _fd {-1};

  public:

    InputStreamBuffer(const int);
    ~InputStreamBuffer();

  protected:

    int sync() override;
    int_type underflow() override;
};

InputStreamBuffer::InputStreamBuffer(const int fd) :
  _fd {fd} {
  setg(_buf, _buf, _buf);
}

InputStreamBuffer::~InputStreamBuffer() {
  if(_buf != _stk) {
    std::free(_buf);
  }
}

int InputStreamBuffer::sync() {

  auto success = int {0};

  while(1) {

    size_t empty = gptr() - eback();
    size_t avail = egptr() - gptr();

    // Before we issue the read, make sure we have enough space.
    if(egptr() == eback() + _size) {
      // Reuse the empty region.
      if(empty > _size / 2) {
        std::memmove(eback(), gptr(), avail);
      }
      // Double the array size.
      else {
        _size = _size * 2;
        auto chunk = static_cast<char_type*>(std::malloc(_size*sizeof(char_type)));
        std::memcpy(chunk, gptr(), avail);
        if(_buf != _stk) std::free(_buf);
        _buf = chunk;
      }
      setg(_buf, _buf, _buf + avail);
    }

    // Read the data.
    issue_read:
    auto ret = ::read(_fd, egptr(), _size - avail);

    if(ret == -1) {
      if(errno == EINTR) {
        goto issue_read;
      }
      if(errno != EAGAIN && errno != EWOULDBLOCK) {
        success = -1;
      }
      break;
    }
    else if(ret == 0) {
      break;
    }

    setg(eback(), gptr(), egptr() + ret);
  }

  return success;
}

InputStreamBuffer::int_type InputStreamBuffer::underflow() {
  int success = sync();
  if(success == -1 || gptr() == egptr()) return traits_type::eof();
  return *(gptr());
}
```

The idea here is to use this streambuffer with non-blocking io. The IO multiplexer will autonomously call `sync` and invoke the user-registered callbacks to perform `istream`-style operations. Simply put, here are some of my questions:

1. The input streambuffer has certain type of operations called "putback". What is the potentially benefit of using the `putback`?
2. The `::read` will return `0` when reaching `EOF`, which is a very useful indicator for signaling the connection status of socket-based IO. What is the best practice to handle this in `sync`? My current implementation simply skips this.
3. Any comments that can improve the implementation will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think this belongs on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mr. Edd](http://www.mr-edd.co.uk/blog/beginners_guide_streambuf)'s very helpful introduction to custom stream buffer implementation,

> Input stream buffers, written for use with istreams, tend to be a little bit more complex than output buffers, written for ostreams. This is because we should endeavor to allow the user to put characters back in to the stream, to a reasonable degree, which is done through the `std::istream`'s `putback()` member function. What this means is that we need to maintain a section at the start of the array for put-back space. Typically, one character of put-back space is expected, though there's no reason we shouldn't be able to provide more, in general.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/39078167/1399272.